# Visual Studio 2010 Automation for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, automation, guidance-automation-tool

I'm new in automation and I could'n find some tutorials or guids how to do that. I found that I could write add-in for visual studio and found that guidance automation can do something what suits me. I tried to create guidance automation project in Visual Studio but some notes in project pointed to Visual Studio 2005. And project icon seemd quit old style. So I thought maybe it's dead.
I would like to do some automation for my mvc project. I have to do a lot fo similar forms. So I decided it would be great to havo some automation. Things I would like to do: 
when I'm creating controller I would like to select entity
create controller class from my defined t4 template
create tests in my test project from t4 template
create model class in Model folder
ceeate command class

In your opinion what would be best solution to aproach that?
And maybe anyone knows any resources where to start.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Mvc Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/) package available through [nuget](http://nuget.org).

Comment: Nice. I also found a video about mvc scaffolding http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Steve-Sanderson-MvcScaffolding